# Spring Data MongoDB Sorting not working as expected

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Sample Mongodb collection

```
[
{"sno":4,"data":"data-4"},
{"sno":3,"data":"data-3"},
{"sno":2,"data":"data-2"},
{"sno":1,"data":"data-1"},
]
```

Spring Data Code:

```
PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(page--, size);
return dao.findAll(pageable);
```

If I pass page as 1 and size as 1, i m getting the below result, which is correct.

```
{"sno":4,"data":"data-4"}
```

If I pass page as 1 and size as 2, see the below
Expected:

```
{"sno":4,"data":"data-4"}
{"sno":3,"data":"data-3"}
```

Actual:
    {"sno":3,"data":"data-3"}
    {"sno":2,"data":"data-2"}

It skips the first record, looks like its a issue with Spring Data for mongodb implementation. I have tried with explicit `Sort(DESC,"sno")` in pageable, still same result.

Did anyone experience this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `page` starts from `0`.

I've tried the same data as you and actually if I call:

```
PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sno"));
dao.findAll(pageable);
```

I will get:

```
{"sno":4,"data":"data-4"}
```

The same if you need first two records in order just call with

```
new PageRequest(0, 2, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sno"));
```

Comment: I thought the same and did it, But i get different result. Thats the reason for raising this question here.,
`{"sno":3,"data":"data-3"}
{"sno":2,"data":"data-2"}`

Comment: What mongo db, spring data versions do you have?

Comment: Sorry, Its my mistake. I have used the wrong decrement of the page parameter as its zero based.
`PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(--page, size);
PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(page--, size);`